# How to have 2 containers connect to other container using TCP in docker network

Tags: docker, networking, network-programming, docker-network

I have this right now:

```
docker network rm cprev || echo;
docker network create cprev || echo;

docker run --rm -d -p '3046:3046' \
    --net=cprev --name 'cprev-server' cprev-server

docker run --rm -d -p '3046:3046' \
    -e cprev_user_uuid=111 --net=cprev --name 'cprev-agent-1' cprev-agent

docker run --rm -d -p '3046:3046' \
    -e cprev_user_uuid=222 --net=cprev --name 'cprev-agent-2' cprev-agent
```

basically the 2 cprev-agents are supposed to connect to the cprev-server using TCP. The problem is I am getting this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint cprev-agent-1
>   (6e65bccf74852f1208b32f627dd0c05b3b6f9e5e7f5611adfb04504ca85a2c11):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:3046 failed: port is already allocated.

I am sure it's a simple fix but frankly I don't know how to allow two way traffic from the two agent containers without using the same port etc.

Comment: You're telling all three containers to listen on the host port 3046, which leads to that error.  You don't need a `-p` option for inter-container communication; does removing this option  on at least 2 of these containers help?

Comment: the answer I added works - but that uses the host network - I am wondering how to use a custom network which does not interfere with the host network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked (using --network=host) but I am wondering how I can create a custom network that doesn't interfere with the host network??

```
docker network create cprev;  # unused now

docker run --rm -d -e cprev_host='0.0.0.0' \
    --network=host --name 'cprev-server' "cprev-server:$curr_uuid"


docker run --rm -d -e cprev_host='0.0.0.0' \
    -e cprev_user_uuid=111 --network=host --name 'cprev-agent-1' "cprev-agent:$curr_uuid"

docker run --rm -d -e cprev_host='0.0.0.0' \
    -e cprev_user_uuid=222 --network=host --name 'cprev-agent-2' "cprev-agent:$curr_uuid"
```

so is there anyway to get this to work using my custom docker network "cprev"?